# Slider to rotate a square

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I have to use a slider to change the angle of my rotating square :

**JS**

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;
var direction = true;
var degrees = 0;

var NumVertices  = 36;

var points = [];
var colors = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;


var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var thetaLoc;

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    colorCube();

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );


    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");

    //event listeners for buttons

    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };

    // Start or Stop
    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                         if (direction == true)
                         direction = false;
                         else
                         direction = true;
                         });

    // SLIDER
    document.getElementById("slide").onchange = function(){
        degrees = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    };


    render();
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

function quad(a, b, c, d)
{
    var vertices = [
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // green
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // blue
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // magenta
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // cyan
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]   // white
    ];

    // We need to parition the quad into two triangles in order for
    // WebGL to be able to render it.  In this case, we create two
    // triangles from the quad indices

    //vertex color assigned by the index of the vertex

    var indices = [ a, b, c, a, c, d ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );
        //colors.push( vertexColors[indices[i]] );

        // for solid colored faces use
        colors.push(vertexColors[a]);

    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (direction == false){
        theta[axis] == degrees;
      //theta[axis] = degrees;

    }
    else  {
        theta[axis] += 2.0;
    }



    /// How to control the rotation degree ?


    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    requestAnimFrame( render );


}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Exercise1_1.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>

<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>

<input type="button" value="Start or Stop" />

<div>
Angle 0 <input id="slide" type="range"
min="0" max="10" step="1" value="1" />
10 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This square must stop when I click the button and restart the rotation if I click it again and this task works. The problem is that I have to change the angle using the slider and it works too if I remove the comment in the last if statement.

The problem is that if I click the start button and then I stop it , it stops in the beginning position and not in the last/current position (this happens if I remove the comment from the if statement code , if I leave the comment the start/stop works well but I can not change the angle).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, this line is wrong `theta[axis] == degrees;`
As you can see you have 2x `=` so you compare the `theta[axis]` with the `degrees`. This means that this line does nothing.

You want to stop the movement of the cube if the button is pressed and start it if it is pressed again, so thats why you have the variable `direction`.

If the `direction` is `true`, then you cube must move, so your `theta[axis]` should increase. If your `direction` is `false` your cube should stay still, so `theta[axis]` must keep its value.

So something like this:

```
// If cube is moving
if (direction == true) {
    theta[axis] += 2.0;
}
// If no movement
else {
    // Do nothing
    // the theta[axis] stays the same
}
```

But now your cube is rotating with the same speed...
Maybe you want your cube to rotate with the `degrees` speed.

So you should change the static value of `2.0` to the variable `degrees`
that gets its value from the slider.

---

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;
var direction = true;
var degrees = 1.0; // Slider starts from value 1.0 as it has value="1" on it

var NumVertices  = 36;

var points = [];
var colors = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;


var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var thetaLoc;

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    colorCube();

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );


    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");

    //event listeners for buttons

    document.getElementById( "xButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = xAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "yButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = yAxis;
    };
    document.getElementById( "zButton" ).onclick = function () {
        axis = zAxis;
    };

    // Start or Stop
    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (direction == true)
            direction = false;
        else
            direction = true;
    });

    // SLIDER
    document.getElementById("slide").onchange = function(){
        // As this is an event of the slider,
        // here inside the handler, the variable `this`
        // points to the slider, so we can do `this.value`
        // to get the slider's value
        degrees = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    };

    render();
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

function quad(a, b, c, d)
{
    var vertices = [
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // green
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // blue
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // magenta
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // cyan
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]   // white
    ];

    // We need to parition the quad into two triangles in order for
    // WebGL to be able to render it.  In this case, we create two
    // triangles from the quad indices

    //vertex color assigned by the index of the vertex

    var indices = [ a, b, c, a, c, d ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );
        //colors.push( vertexColors[indices[i]] );

        // for solid colored faces use
        colors.push(vertexColors[a]);
    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (direction != false){
        theta[axis] += degrees;
        // theta[axis] is increased by the degrees variable
        // that is being updated with the value of the slider
        // every time we slide the slider
    }

    // How to control the rotation degree ?
    // With a nice slider! ...

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

Comment: I don't think  that this is a speed problem , this is my task : "Add a slider to control the angle of rotation (from 0 to 10 degrees)" The speed is not relevant.

Comment: `Rotational speed` is the `rotation degrees in a spesific time`. Since you rotate the cube on every `requestAnimFrame` this means that you change the Rotational speed.

Comment: Anyway, the `speed` is not the mater here... If you don't want to change the `speed` just leave the `2.0` value. But this makes your slider do nothing.

Comment: Probably the problem is that I did not understand what the task asks ; if I change the angle of rotation , what am I changing ? The speed of the rotation or the view of my square ?

Comment: You may have to ask your teacher. Anyway the point of the exercise is to understand the code and how the things work, so you may need to focus a little more on understanding the code, the solution will be later clear if you do so.